# Show members of a class in Unity3D inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to edit this structure in object inspector just like on screenshot:
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnHE5.jpg)

### Edit

I have a script attached to my main object. it has a member named TestData which itself has two other members I and F.

How can I enable the Unity Inspector to edit TestData by its members (I, F) instead of the reference to TestData, When I click my main object?

Comment: If you are looking for someone to help you, I would recommend reading the help center and then editing your question to add more information. It is generally recommended that you have tried some code prior to asking here and you should post what you have tried and detail where it hasn't worked. Otherwise, this just looks like a requirements dump and this is not a code-writing service. It's a site to help people learn how to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a script in Unity and attach it to a GameObject. The script must be derived from `MonoBehaviour`

You can add public variables to the script and see them in the inspector.

c#:

```
public Vector3 StartPoint;
```

You can add `[System.Serializable]` to the class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TestData
{
     public int I;
     public int F;
}
```

Or if you want the inspector to show something other than the default editor panel you can define a CustomPropertyDrawer for your type.

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(MyScript))]
public class MyScriptDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {

        //...
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
        EditorGUI.LabelField(new Rect(x, y, w, h), "title");
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, I, GUIContent.none);
        //...
    }
}
```